# How to determine admob or chartboost interstitial is displaying?

Tags: admob, interstitial, chartboost

If the interstitial is displaying now, then I don't need to show it again.

Inmobi has the function: `if(inmobInterstitial.state==kIMInterstitialStateActive)` , how about admob and chartboost?

I have integrated admob,inmobi and chartboost in my app. If anyone is still loading or not ready, then I pop up anyone which is ready. When chartboost is displaying now, but the app don't know it, then pop up inmobi. It's the bug.

Comment: Instead of managing the 3 different networks yourself, I strongly recommend you use a mediator to handle it for your.

Comment: I can't believe mediator, they may steal in their server. Right?

Comment: ?? I don't know what you are asking or suggesting. A mediator lets you make a single request (to the mediator) and they will poll the ad networks that you have configured them with for an ad. The first ad that is returned is given to you to display. Admob provides a mediator out of the box.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I don't believe in mediator, they are not open source, if they make a part of the ads requesting in their own id, I will lose money. They may steal a part of requests for themselves. Some mediator can configure ads at the sever. I've written the same functions in my app and my own server.

Comment: @William Which mediator do you recommend?mobfox,mopub,or any others?

Comment: I use Admob to mediate.

Comment: In China, Admob is sometimes banned, then Admob mediate also can't get data. And sometimes, admob interstitial is still loading, not ready to display, then I can pop up inmobi interstitial. What alternative ad platform do you recommend?